# Can I install maverick's sound menu in lucid?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, sound

Luci runs better for me, without many annoying bugs, but I like the sound menu from maverick. Can I install it in lucid, without upgrading?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, among other upgrades found in maverick sound menu relies on MPRIS support in your music player, which is only found in maverick.